# C# fill a cell in tableLayoutPanel on a loop

Tags: c#, tablelayoutpanel

I have a problem in this code, that show me own cell filled.

Here is the code:

```
private void tableLayoutPanel1_CellPaint(object sender, TableLayoutCellPaintEventArgs e)
{
   for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
   {
      if (j % 3 == 0)
      {
         if (e.Column == j && e.Row == 1)
         {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, e.CellBounds);
         }
      }

      else
      {
         if (e.Column == j && e.Row == 1)
         {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Brown, e.CellBounds);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

And here the result:
http://prntscr.com/20e3pb

Comment: What is the problem again?

Comment: You have shown some code and a picture but nothing to explain what the problem is and nothing to explain what you want the code to do.

Comment: did you mean (j+1)%3 == 0 instead?